# PyDev: Running Code in local machine to remote machine

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Would you please let me know, how would I run my code in local machine to remote server?
I have source code and data in local machine. But I would like to run the code in remote server.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be:

1. Install python on the remote machine
2. Package your code into a python package using distutils (see http://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial). Basically the process ends when you run the command `python setup sdist` in the root dir of your project, and get a tar.gz file in the dist/ subfolder.
3. Copy your package to the remote server using scp, for example, if it is an amazon machine:

   scp -i  myPemFile.pem local-python-package.tar.gz remote_user_name@remote_ip:remote_folder
4. Run `sudo pip install local-python-package.tar.gz` on the remote server
5. Now you can either SSH to the remote machine and run your code or use some remote enabler such as [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/) to start commands on the remote server (works for any shell command, specifically python scripts)

Alternatively, you can just skip the package building in [2], if you have a simple script, just scp the script itself to the remote machine ane proceed using a remote `python myscript.py`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting up git repository on repote server and connect local source (for git you can read about how to do it here: http://git-scm.com/book).

Then you can use i.e. Eclipse EGit and after you change your local code you can push it to remote location.